# ListView items don't display immediately on startup

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I have a strange glitch with my program. I'm trying to follow a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXmiZl03Rb4&index=11&list=PLfBjz1j1UV9m3MofrgMivwaGjRjfhMQfL) in regards to generating and displaying listView items using firebase.

The problem with my program is that on start up I cannot see any of my list items however when I start to create a new item the list populates itself with all my previous entries and my newly created one.

From my research on similar problems there has been talk of using notifydatasetchanged to update my listview however some people have said that when calling an ArrayAdapter there is no need to do this as data is constantly being updated.

```
**CustomAdapter Class**

/**
 * Created by MarkB on 14/03/2017.
 */

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<User> users;

    public CustomAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.c = c;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return users.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,viewGroup,false);
        }

        //Find TextView items on the model.xml
        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        TextView surnameTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.surnameTxt);
        TextView ageTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageTxt);
        TextView weightTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weightTxt);
        TextView genderTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genderTxt);

        final User u = (User) this.getItem(position);

        nameTxt.setText(u.getName());
        surnameTxt.setText(u.getSurname());
        ageTxt.setText(u.getAge());
        weightTxt.setText(u.getWeight());
        genderTxt.setText(u.getGender());

        //ONITEMCLICK
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(c,"Hi " + u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent startMenuActivity = new Intent(c, Menu_Activity.class);
                c.startActivity(startMenuActivity);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Home_Screen_Activity Class*

```
public class Home_Screen_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper helper;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText nameTxt, surnameTxt, ageTxt, weightTxt;
    Spinner genderSpinner;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //INITIALISE FIREBASE DB
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);

        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                displayInputDialog();
            }

        });
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    private void displayInputDialog() {
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Save To Firebase");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);

        nameTxt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        surnameTxt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.surnameEditText);
        ageTxt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.ageEditText);
        weightTxt = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.weightEditText);
        genderSpinner = (Spinner) d.findViewById(R.id.genderSpinner);

        Button saveBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //GET DATA
                String name = nameTxt.getText().toString();
                String surname = surnameTxt.getText().toString();
                String age = ageTxt.getText().toString();
                String weight = weightTxt.getText().toString();
                String gender = genderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


                //SET DATA
                User u = new User();
                u.setName(name);
                u.setSurname(surname);
                u.setAge(age);
                u.setWeight(weight);
                u.setGender(gender);

                //SIMPLE VALIDATION
                if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
                    //THEN SAVE
                    if (helper.save(u)) {
                        //IF SAVED CLEAR EDITTXT
                        nameTxt.setText("");
                        surnameTxt.setText("");
                        ageTxt.setText("");
                        weightTxt.setText("");
                        genderSpinner.setSelection(0);


                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(Home_Screen_Activity.this, helper.retrieve());
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Home_Screen_Activity.this, "Name Must Not Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        d.show();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I honestly don't understand where this glitch is coming from. There is no mention of this glitch in my logcat either

Comment: Move `helper.retrieve()` out and place before `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: didn't seem to work. Just crashed the program.

Error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList uk.ac.napier.newsreader.FireBaseHelper.FirebaseHelper.retrieve()' on a null object reference